# WordPress adding get_posts results and re-ordering

Tags: wordpress

I am doing a series of loops which uses:

```
$myposts = get_posts("category=$category->id");
```

Which gets all posts for the given category. However I need to do something like:

```
$myposts .= get_posts("category=$category->id");
```

so the var $myposts is added to on each loop. I then need to re-order $myposts by published date and re-loop.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

My complete code is:

```
global $wpdb;
$categories = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $wpdb->terms.term_id AS id, name, description 

from $wpdb->terms INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id WHERE parent = '2' ORDER BY name ASC");
echo '<ul class="results">';
foreach($categories as $category) :
?>
<?php global $post;
$myposts = get_posts("category=$category->id");
foreach($myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
?>
<li>
<a class="title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span><br/><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
<a class="image" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'result') ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?> 

<?php endforeach; 
echo '</ul>';
```

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the simplest level, you cannot concatenate (use the dot operator as you would on strings) on arrays. try using `array_merge`

```
$myposts = get_posts("category=$category->id");
$myposts = array_merge($myposts, get_posts("category=$category->id"));
```

Although, I think what you are trying to achieve is a listing of posts from several categories correct? The above example will give possible duplicates (if same post is in multiple categories) try the more WP way of doing this:

```
//array of categories
$categories = array();

// I assume you are looping through something to get the multiple `$category->id`
for($some_category_objs as $category)
{
    $categories[] = $category->id;
}

// query for posts where the post has every category in the list
$myposts = query_posts(array('category__and' => $categories));

// query for posts where the post matches any of the categories
$myposts = query_posts('cat='.implode(",", $categories));
```

Your post was a little vague on what your goal was.. let me know if i'm off base. Also, check out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts

### EDIT

```
$args = array(
    'category__in' => $categories, // $categories is an array of all the categories to search in
    'orderby' => 'date', // ORDER  BY DATE
    'order' => 'DESC', // NEWWST FIRST
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Comment: Hi Francis, thanks for helping me. I've added my complete code. The issue I have is that I get all categories with a parent of '2' and loop, getting and adding the posts to a <ul>. This works fine, but they are in category order. I need them to be in published date order instead so the only way I can do this i believe is by adding/merging all the posts into an array, re-ordering by published date and then outputting the <li> elements.

Comment: see my edit. Also you really need to read http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters and http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters and http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts